# Delegate doesn't accept subclass?

Tags: c#, inheritance, delegates

My delegate doens't seem to accept a subclass, I think an example is the easiest.

```
public class A
{
     public A() { }
}

public class B : A
{
     public B() { }
}

public class Program
{
     private delegate void CallBack(A a);
     private static CallBack callBack = new CallBack(Test);

     public Main(string[] args)
     {
          callBack(new B());
     }

     private static void Test(A a)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Test()");    
     }

     // Compilation error occurs if Test becomes:
     private static void Test(B a)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Test()");
     }
 }
```

When I change Test to accept `B` it throws a compilation error. Isn't this odd because `B` extends `A`?

**Compiler error**:

> No overload for Test matches Callback

Is there a way to make my delegate accept a class that extends `A`?

Comment: Does it throw an exception or fails in compilation?

Comment: That shouldn't be causing a problem. Can you paste the changed code here? Just to know how you're changing it?

Comment: @Mamta Dalal - Edited my question, hope this clears it up a bit more.

Comment: You can *pass* a subclass to a delegate, but you cannot create a delegate that *requires* a subclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't odd because if you have an object of class `C` that extends `A`, it wouldn't make sense to pass to `Test()` if it only accepts a `B`. Any method used for a `Callback` has to accept *any* `A`, not just a specific subclass. You would need to change the `Callback` delegate signature to accept `B` if you want to `Test()` to accept `B` as well.

```
class C : A {};

Callback callback = Test;

callback(new C()); //what if Test() accepted B???
```

Comment: So my only option would be to cast `A` to `B` inside of `Test`?

Comment: @Kevin: No, it’s not the only option. A better option is to declare the delegate as `void CallBack(B b)`. You can still use the method `Test(A a)` then.

Comment: @Timwi - I can't do that I'm afraid. I've got a class `Event` that everyone can extend and pass to the delegate.

Comment: @Kevin: Then how do you expect this to be possible? What do you expect to happen if someone passes a `NutellaEvent` to your callback when your method expects a `LoveLetterEvent`?

Comment: @Timwi - Well err.. You've got a point there. Thanks for opening my eyes!

Answer (score 10):

> Isn't this odd because B extends A?

You have the right idea, but in the wrong direction. Let's consider an example that is easier to reason about:

```
class Animal {}
class Reptile : Animal {}
class Snake : Reptile {}
class Mammal : Animal {}
class Tiger : Mammal {}
class Giraffe : Mammal {}
delegate void D(Mammal m);
static void DoAnimal(Animal a) {}
static void DoMammal(Mammal m) {}
static void DoTiger(Tiger t) {}

D dm = DoMammal;
dm(new Tiger());
```

That's clearly legal. dm needs to be a method that takes a Mammal, and it is.

```
D dt = DoTiger;
dt(new Giraffe());
```

That's clearly got to be illegal. You cannot assign a method that takes a tiger to a delegate that takes a mammal, because a delegate that takes a mammal can take any mammal, not just a tiger.  If this were legal then it would be possible to pass a giraffe to a method that takes a tiger.

What about this?

```
D da = DoAnimal;
da(new Giraffe());
```

That's fine.  da is a delegate to a method that takes any mammal. A method that takes any animal clearly also takes any mammal.  You can assign DoAnimal(Animal) to a delegate D(Mammal) because Mammal extends Animal. You see now how you got the direction of extension backwards?

*Return types* on the other hand work the way you think they do:

```
delegate Mammal F();
static Animal GetAnimal() {...}
static Mammal GetMammal() {...}
static Tiger GetTiger() {...}

F fm = GetMammal; 
Mammal m = fm();
```

No problem there.

```
F ft = GetTiger;
Mammal t = ft();
```

No problem there; GetTiger returns a Tiger, so you can assign it to a delegate that requires that its target returns a mammal.

```
F fa = GetAnimal;
Mammal a = fa();
```

That's no good. GetAnimal might return a Snake, and now you have a variable typed as Mammal that contains a Snake.  This has to be illegal.

This feature is called "covariance and contravariance of member group conversions" and it was introduced in C# 2.0. For more information on this topic see my article on it:

https://ericlippert.com/2007/10/19/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-3-method-group-conversion-variance/

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to understand. Now we have:

```
class A { }
class B : A { }
```

**Scenario 1** at the beginning

```
public delegate void CallBack(A a);
public void Test(A a) { }
CallBack cb = new CallBack(Test);
cb(new A()); //good and easy usage
```

**Scenario 2** `CallBack(A a)` and `Test(B b)`

```
//compile error, because Test(B b) has a smaller argument scope than CallBack
//CallBack cb = new CallBack(Test);
```

**Scenario 3** `CallBack(B b)` and `Test(A a)`

```
CallBack cb = new CallBack(Test);
cb(new A());  //no error, becasue B can convert to A
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up. I guess I will have to cast `A` to `B` then, too bad..

Answer (score -1):

C# delegates [support both covariance and contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173174(VS.80).aspx), so this should work.

The problem is the overload.

```
 // this delegate supports contravariance - and subclass of A should work
 delegate void CallBack(A a);

 // however this can't pick up either Test because both could be used
 static CallBack callBack = new CallBack(Test);
```

Which overload method signature (`Test(A a)` or `Test(B b)`) has to be resolved at compile time - however both could apply, so an error is thrown.

You could avoid this by splitting out the overload:

```
 static void TestA(A a)
 {
      Console.WriteLine("Test(a)");    
 }

 // Compilation error occurs if Test becomes:
 static void TestB(B a)
 {
      Console.WriteLine("Test(b)");
 }

 // this is valid because it's an exact match
 static CallBack callBackA = new CallBack(TestA);

 // this is valid because delegates support contravariance 
 static CallBack callBackB = new CallBack(TestB);
```

In either case you can pass a `B`:

```
// B is subclass of A, so can be passed to TestA
callBackA(new B());

// CallBack supports contravariance, so can call TestB
callBackB(new B());
```

Given that you have this contravariance, why do you need the overloads?

Comment: I'm trying to recreate the eventlistener model of Flash in C# :) - Thanks for the answer! The biggest problem is that users need to be able to extend my `Event` class and pass their class to the delegate.

Comment: contravariance only works when the argument is a **less derived** type than the one in the delegate declaration. You can never assign a method taking an argument `B` to the delegate you've declared. On the other hand, if the delegate was declared to take an argument `B`, you would be able to add a method of argument `A`