# Generic type as a delegate parameter

Tags: c#

Assume I have the following delegate:

```
public delegate void ExampleDelegate(IMessage msg);
```

Can I use the above `delegate` in a class where I make `IMessage` a Generic Type? As follows:

```
public class ExampleClass<TGenericType> where TGenericType: IMessage
{
    public void UsageDelegate(TGenericType message)
    {

    }
}
```

I tried it but I'm getting:

> No overload for 'UsageDelegate' matches delegate 'ExampleDelegate'

In my opinion, there should be a way to accomplish this, just can't find out how. Can someone help me?

Comment: Show how the code that give that message

Comment: See [c# - Delegate doesn't accept subclass? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733551/delegate-doesnt-accept-subclass )

Comment: Can you not just use `IMessage` instead? For example: `UsageDelegate(IMessage message)`... does that not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UsageDelegate` is no `ExampleDelegate` plain and simple. An `ExampleDelegate` must be able to take *any* `IMessage`, your `UsageDelegate`only accepts one *specific* implementation of `IMessage`.

The only way to accomplish this is to rethink what you want to do and build your solution accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
public void UsageDelegate(IMessage message)
{

}
```

On this way, you can call UsageDelegate passing any generic types that implements IMessage to it.

The interface has a smaller scope than the generic type. 
If you uses the generic type as parameter, you have a bigger object scope than the delegate implements. That would cause an invalid access to Generic Type properties if you try to acess it inside the method.

You can cast IMessage > Generic Type.

But if you use like you posted, its like trying to cast

GenericT_A to GenericT_B just because both implements the same Interface, and that's not necessarily valid.